# iOS: How to get a modal view to partially cover the parent view?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, interface-builder, modal-dialog

I am quite new in iOS development and I am facing an issue with the design of navigation. So my goal is simple: I have a view with a right navigation button which I want to open a modal view that would **partially cover** the parent view like on this screenshot: [modal view example](https://moo.mx/grabs/38465568.png)

Currently this is what I did: I embedded a UIViewController in a UINavigationController, then I added a right navigation button in my view controller which navigates to another UIViewController through a modal action segue. But whenever I navigate to the modal view, it **fully covers** the parent view.

So how can I get it to only cover partially the parent view with Interface Builder settings? Or do I need to use some code behind to achieve that?

Thanks for your help :)

NB: I don't want to use Popovers, I want it to be in the middle of the screen with no attach.

[image: IBScreenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you have to select your segue and modify the `Presentation` property to `Form Sheet`, as shown in the image below

[image]